# Game with multiple stages that can be locked/unlocked/finished

Tags: buttons, labels, user-centered-design

I am working on a learning platform, that offers users a number of games. Users take games one by one, and for each game they can see their current status in overview.

- A game has multiple stages that user can be upon.
- Stages are locked, till user finishes the preceding stage.
- Once user finishes a stage, next one remains locks for some time.
- User can open a game and see his progression in the game.
- If stage is available, user decides to play
- There can be bonus if user plays the game immediately

This is how we present the overview of a game progress to user:

[image]

The overall look and feel is that of a simple and elegant website (no fancy visuals).

Any cool ideas on a more communicative way of doing it ?

Comment: What you have seems clear (though I'm not sure you have given us enough context to fully answer).  But it also might be worth considering alternatives that use the "metaphor" of the game, if that's relevant.

Comment: I think what is missing is the current game that they are playing.

Comment: @DimitraMiha Makes sense, need to indicate the current level in the game

Comment: So the only way to unlock the next stage is to a) complete the previous stage, and then b) wait for 'some time'. Once both A and B are complete the  next stage will become active? Because if that is true then probably you want to indicate a timer of some sort against the 'about to be unlocked' stage.

Comment: yeap, timer is indeed required.

Comment: As of now, this looks like an admin panel. A place where you are seeing which user is at what stage and making some decision for him. From a user's and business perspective, if it is a game, it needs to have more zing. The timers and unlocks are okay, but the jazziness counts in a game. Writing this as a comment, because this is not really an answer but a thought about presentation specific to a game. I'd rather have you comment more about the context of the game, the rewards, achievements etc.

Comment: @Harshal Makes sense. Its a learning game, that consists of a number of quizzes. Learners take quiz one by one, and for each quiz they can see their current status in overview. Yeah, jazziness is good to have, but this is not a regular rich graphics experience, more like a simple elegant website.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the comments, you could show the time as an overlay. What I'm not sure about is if you still need the lock behind, since it's both not available but also already unlocked:

[image]

Comment: up-vote for suggestion of timer inside the locked stage.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am going ahead with for the time being :

[image: Currently going ahead with this design]

I am still not very sure. This one needs so much extra height, would love to hear more ideas.